# How can I get org-mode clocktables to display (and sum up) appointments, like meetings for example?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, org-clock-table

Well, it is basically what the title says. I have the need to use clocktables to generate work reports, but I would like my meetings and other appointments to show up in the clocktables as well. I know that I could clock-in and then clock-out of the appointment to force them to show up in the clocktables, but I was wondering if there was some other (simpler) method.

Thanks in advance.